# How can I add Sci-Hub as a search engine for Chrome?

Tags: search, google-chrome

I would like to add Sci-Hub as a search engine from the Chrome omnibox. This mostly just requires a way to feed the search to Sci-Hub as a URL, but the format is proving harder to find than I thought. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I use `http://sci-hub.se//%s`. Double slashes after `.se` because I usually paste URLs there and it would cut the start of it for some reason.

**Edit**: typo.

Answer (score -2):

The trick is to search for %s and you will find the correct URL. In this case this is:

https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%s

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Sci-Hub != Google Sholar